# small horizontal scrollview with UIButtons

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton

I want to create a small horizontal scrollview with few buttons as shown in image. User can select any one of them and details will be shown accordingly. I am not sure how to code it programmatically. Please help.

Image:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDqkn.jpg

Answer (score 1):

ok follow steps to implement the same.

step 1 : take UITableview and apply affin transform for 90 degree.
step 2 : take a button on each cell also apply affinetransform of 90 degree.
step 3 : for each table cell height (now you can say width) will be calculated with the help of stringwidth function of NSString. so please type code in call back method (heightforRowatIndexPath).
step 4 : take layer of tableview and apply round corner property with value 10.0f
step 5 : same you can do for the button their color.

step 6: for outer arrow yo need to implement some UIScrollview module.

### here all memory will be managed by tableview for n number of buttons in horizontal scrolling.

Thanks,
Please let me know for any issue

Answer (score 0):

In an ARC view controller ...

```
#define kHEIGHT  35.0

- (void)createButtonScrollViewWithButtonTitles:(NSArray *)titles {

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,100.0,320.0,kHEIGHT)];

    CGFloat buttonPositionX = 0.0;
    for (NSString *title in titles) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(buttonPositionX, 0.0, 90.0, kHEIGHT);
        buttonPositionX += 90.0;
        [scrollView addSubview:button];
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(buttonPositionX, kHEIGHT);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

After you get this working, you can create a version that takes an array of images.   For that, the button type will change to UIButtonTypeCustom.  You'll use setImage: rather than setTitle: and you'll have the chance to vary the width by advancing buttonPositionX by the image.size.width, rather than a constant.

Not sure how to interpret the little scroll-arrow-looking things on each side of the image you posted.  Another subsequent enhancement would be to overlay each end with a little image view (with userInteractionEnabled = NO) that matches those arrow things.